# Autofit table header width in Flexigrid

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

Im using the Jquery Plugin Flexigrid as datagrid in my web app. How can I autofit the width of my table header using FlexiGrid? If you dont specify a width to the tag `<th>` the width of the `<td>` table will be different from the width of `<th>` and the header will be displaced from the rest of the table.